# Creating a dropdown menu with JSON input stored in a txt file

Tags: javascript, html, json, local-files

I am trying to create a drop-down list with JSON data stored in a txt file. My main issue is reading the data (I saved the data which I retrieved from an API into a txt file because it is a large amount of data and I wanted to save time by not having to make a request to the API every time the data is needed)

*As a side note, not entirely sure that getting the data in the form of JSON is the best option. Other options supported by this API are: CSV, JSONP, serialized PHP, and XML (if one of those would be easier)

Here is the form of the JSON data (stored as a string in classes.txt):

```
{
    "classes": [
        {
            "cat_num": "0001",
            "field": "OEB",
            "number": "363",
            "title": "Plant Diversity and Evolution"
        },
        {
            "cat_num": "0002",
            "term": "FALL",
            "bracketed": false,
            "field": "OEB",
            "number": "364",
            "title": "Ecological Physiology of Microbes"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my code for trying to populate the dropdown menu with this txt file thus far

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    var url = "classes.txt";
    $.get(url, function(data) {
    var obj = eval('(' + data + ')');
    $.each(obj, function(i, option){    
        $('#department').append($('<option/>')
                        .attr("value",option.cat_num)
                        .text(option.field));
      );
  );

    });
```

I've also realized that I need to somehow make sure that "field" is unique in my drop down (i.e. if 3 classes are of the field "OEB", I just want OEB to appear in my drop down once, not 3 times)

Thanks in advance for any help you might be able to provide!

Comment: There is syntax error, missing "}",
and try use .getJSON()

Answer (score 0):

here this could help

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('classes.txt', function(data) {

      $.each(data, function(i, option){        
            console.log(option.title)
            $('#department').append($('<option/>').attr("value",option.cat_num).text(option.title));
      });
    });
});
```